# Referring to Jframe from separate class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have a GUI that I initialize using "this." as follows:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    //constructor
    public GUI() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        this.getContentPane().setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
        this.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setTitle("GUI");
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 1919, 1080);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        etc.
    }
}
```

I want to use the .setCursor method from a separate class on the frame created in my GUI class.

```
public class OtherClass {
    public static void OtherClassMethod() {
        *something*.setCursor(...);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to refer to the frame initialized in my GUI class so I can use setCursor etc in that separate class, or do I need to make all methods referring to the frame in the GUI class? I'm only using the setCursor method in a separate class for organizational reasons, so I could put it back in the main GUI class if need be, and use this.setCursor(...) there instead.

Also, if trying to do this is bad programming practice, I apologize, and please give me a reason why it is such, as I would like to learn from this.

As per the accepted answer, I altered my code as such:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static GUI gui;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        gui = new GUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    //constructor
    public GUI() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        this.getContentPane().setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
        this.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setTitle("GUI");
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 1919, 1080);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        etc.
    }
}
```

I'm going to leave my original code as well as the altered code for learning. Obviously, this issue was fixed very easily and I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of it myself, but it was not apparent to me right away. Hopefully someone else can learn from this.

Comment: You could consider having the other class provide a method that returns a  cursor (static, a la a factory). From GUI you could then call that method to get the cursor and apply it to your frame from within GUI.

Comment: did you not know that you could have a variable like that, or did you just have a brain-fart?

Comment: More of a brain fart than anything. I have dozens of other static variables declared in that way, but it didn't occur to me that I could create a static variable of type GUI. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problemo mis amigo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic java:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static GUI gui;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        gui = new GUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
```

Now, simply put GUI.gui.setCursor (etc.)